# Nginx, redirection on subfolder not working

Tags: nginx, proxypass

I can make Nginx respond to www.example.com. But I'd like to redirect www.example.com/site0 to one specific server and www.example.com/site1 to another. It works When I point to the root location www.example.com.

But I can't make Nginx resolve www.example.com/site0 to one specific server

Here is my configuration:

```
 server {

    listen       80;
    server_name  www.example.com localhost;

    location /site0/ {
       proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:5000;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

}
```

Trying to access www.example.com/site0/ return

```
192.168.0.254 - - [14/Mar/2018:21:13:28 +0100] "GET /site0 HTTP/1.1" 301 185 "-" "curl/7.54.0"
192.168.0.254 - - [14/Mar/2018:21:13:31 +0100] "GET /site0/ HTTP/1.1" 404 233 "-" "curl/7.54.0"
```

I don't understand why this is not working. I am using this example in order to configure my server:
https://gist.github.com/soheilhy/8b94347ff8336d971ad0

**edit** :(
the error was:

```
   proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:5000/;
```

Note the slash at the end of the target url. I don't know why this is not important for location '/'

Answer (score 0):

Quite a big difference between

```
 proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:5000;
```

And

```
 proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
```